# Is there a standardization group that determines rules for naming geometric figures?

Tags: geometry, terminology

Does a group or union that determined the names of geometric figures exist? I know that unions like IUPAC (International union of pure and applied chemistry) and IUPAP (International union of pure and applied physics) standardize the symbols and models used in chemistry and physics respectively, but does a union like this exist for geometry or mathematics altogether?

Comment: No.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: We can't even decide if the set of [Natural Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) includes zero! :) Mathematical literature is replete with multiple names for certain things and multiple things for certain names. Fun! That said, the [International Organization for Standardization (ISO)](https://iso.org) has compiled some [standards for math symbols](https://www.iso.org/standard/64973.html). (They say zero is a natural, by the way.) Also, individual publications (and/or their referees) have certain conventions they want upheld, so there are *pockets* of consistency out there.

Comment: Which kind of geometric figures are you thinking about ? Polyhedra for example ?

Comment: yes, that's right.

Comment: For a discussion of polyhedral naming conventions, see [this by George Hart](https://www.georgehart.com/virtual-polyhedra/naming.html). Names get cumbersome, so many highly-symmetric figures are described using [Conway polyhedron notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_polyhedron_notation), which provides recipes for building polyhedra from basic forms using a collection of operations (dualization, truncation, etc). (RIP John H. Conway, 2020.) The [Polyhedronisme webapp](http://levskaya.github.io/polyhedronisme/) renders polyhedra based on recipes you can enter.